# Adding existing key for Git in Cygwin

Tags: git, bash, configuration, cygwin, console2

I have my key set up as inpdenedent GIT installation for our local repo. I can do all git commands from git bash prompot. Recently, I installed cygwin and want to use git from there.

I tried running ssh-add command and it didn't work ... see below

```
user@computer_name /cygdrive/d/folder/cheftesting
$ ssh-add /cygdrive/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
      0 [main] ssh-add 8656 stdio_init: couldn't make stderr distinct from stdout

user@computer_name /cygdrive/d/folder/cheftesting
$ git clone git@gitlab.domain.net:project-chef/proj.git
Cloning into 'proj'...
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.domain.net (ip_address)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: If you created a new key for cygwin, you need to add that new public key to the remote git server